# Selenium - Set the presence of an element as a Boolean and then execute 'if' and 'else' code

Tags: java, selenium

I am currently writing a test script, in java on selenium, which is looking at elements on the webpage and if present writing them into a text file.

The issue I have is that the element may or may not be on the page, depending on *other* variables.

I am trying to get the code to set whether the element is present as a boolean, and if present complete execute the 'if block', if the element is not present I want it to go to 'else' and continue with the script.

Here's my current effort, however during execution (when the element is not present) the script is ending in exception, in the if block (because the element is not present), when I don't expect it to enter in the first place.

```
// First check if the element exists (attempting to make boolean)
boolean isPresent; Login.driver.findElements
(By.xpath("html/body/div[4]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]"));

// If true write values to .txt file, else continue with script           
        if (true){

        writer.write(Login.driver.findElement
                (By.xpath("html/body/div[4]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a"))
                .getText() + " : " + Login.driver.findElement
                (By.xpath("html/body/div[4]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]"))
                .getText());
        writer.write(lineSeparator);}
        else
```

Can anyone see where I have gone wrong?

Comment: `if (true)` will always execute. Is this pseudo-code or an actual snippet?

Comment: This was an actual snippet. I could not work out why 'if (true)' was not working myself. Your answer below has given me the solution to my issue, works perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK first of all I'm assuming you are using Selenium WebDriver and not Selenium RC.

You need to assign the `boolean` to true if the elements exist.
Assuming that:

```
Login.driver.findElements(
   By.xpath("html/body/div[4]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]"));
```

Can find the elements (I don't personally recommend traversing the DOM tree), then you just need to check if it did and report that to the `isPresent` boolean.

Since `findElements` returns a `List` you need to check if its size is greater than 0.

And you assign the result to the boolean like so:

```
boolean isPresent = (Login.driver.findElements(
    By.xpath("html/body/div[4]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]")).size() > 0);
```

Then just put your boolean in the `if` conditional `if(isPresent)` and it will only execute when the elements are found.

Comment: Works perfect for me. Thanks Ceiling Gecko. I also appreciate the explanation of the functions and I am still a novice at this.